# Testing Spring MVC Request Parameter Map and MultipartFile with MockMVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a RESTful controller endpoint with Spring MVC 3.2 to upload a file as well as a map of metadata for that file.  Defined like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/file")
public class FileServiceController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void upload(@RequestParam MultipartFile file,
                       @RequestParam String fileType,
                       @RequestParam(value="metadata") Map<String, List<String>> metadata) {
        // TODO: stuff with things
    }
}
```

which I'm then trying to test like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppConfig.class })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ProductIngestServiceControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Mock
    private FileServiceController controller;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpload() {
        MockMultipartFile mockFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", "This is a test file".getBytes());
        Map<String, List<String>> metadata = new HashMap<>();
        metadata.put("custom0", Arrays.asList("test1", "test2"));
        metadata.put("custom1", Arrays.asList("test3", "test4", "test5"));
        metadata.put("custom2", Arrays.asList("test6"));

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String mapStr = gson.toJson(metadata);

        mockMvc.perform(fileUpload(baseURL + "/test")
            .file(mockFile)
            .param("fileType", "test_type")
            .param("metadata", mapStr))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the map to contain just the "customX" entries, but it contains all request parameters instead (except the MultipartFile...).

If I try:

```
public void upload(@RequestParam MultiValueMap parameters) {
    ...
}
```

the MultipartFile isn't included in that map either.

Am I going about this the wrong way?  The only solution I can come up with at the moment is to just use a String for the metadata RequestParam and do something like:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonFactory factory = mapper.getJsonFactory();

JsonParser jp = factory.createJsonParser(testMap);
Map<String, List<String>> map = jp.readValueAs(Map.class);
```

but that feels dirty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: So is the issue that you cannot get the MultipartFile or that there are values in metadata that shouldn't be there?

Answer (score 0):

Use MockHttpServletRequest.

```
@Before
public void before() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
            .dispatchOptions(true).build();
    MockHttpServletRequest request;= new MockHttpServletRequest();
    Map<String, List<String>> metadata=request.getParameter("metadata");
}
```